# Is there a way/program to count the discharge cycles of my laptop battery?

Tags: linux, battery

I have read posts online that after a number of discharge cycles (~30 cycles) you must perform a calibration by doing a full discharge, then letting the battery rest for 5-10 hours and then a full discharge. It helps keep your battery Wear Level down and extends your battery life. In Windows I use the Battery Care utility. Is there a similar program (or combination of programs) to help count the discharge cycles?

Comment: Check your battery technology: the conditioning advice will vary by battery type. I often hear people give and receive advice that is only true of battery types that are no longer in use. This advice just keeps going around, spread by people trying to look clever, but just repeating what they where told. ( I have no idea if the advice you where give is relevant for you laptop, I am not saying one way or the other. What I am saying is do your research. )